# Why does my user supplied label in geom_text in ggplot2 generate an error?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

First some background. I'm trying to create a waterfall plot using ggplot2. I have written the following function that does the trick. However, I have a small issue when trying to provide a user supplied formatting function for the geom_text label.

```
plotIt<-function()
{
  require(ggplot2)
  require(scales)

  # Define formatting functions
  formatter<-function(x, ...) format(x, big.mark = ' ', trim = TRUE, scientific = FALSE, ...)
  strwr<-function(x) gsub(" ", "\n", x)

  # Build data frame to plot
  mydf<-structure(list(Description = structure(1:6, .Label = LETTERS[1:6], class = "factor"), 
                       change = c(0.86, 0.14, 0.08, -0.05, -0.03, 1.00), 
                       id = 1:6, 
                       end = c(0.86, 1.00, 1.08, 1.03, 1.00, 0.00), 
                       start = c(0, 0.86, 1.00, 1.08, 1.03, 1.00), 
                       type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Neg", "Pos"), class = "factor")), 
                  .Names = c("Description", "change", "id", "end", "start", "type"), 
                  row.names = LETTERS[1:6], class = "data.frame")

  # Plot it
  ggplot(mydf, aes(Description, fill = type)) + 
    geom_rect(aes(x = Description, xmin = id - 0.45, xmax = id + 0.45, ymin = end, ymax = start)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = formatter) +
    scale_x_discrete("", breaks = levels(mydf$Description), labels = strwr(levels(mydf$Description))) +
    geom_text(aes(x = id, y = end, label = formatter(change)), vjust = 1, size = 3)
}
```

Calling this function generates the following error message:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "formatter"

The culprit is the label = formatter(change) code in the last row geom_text. If I replace it with label = comma(change) everything works fine. The "comma" function comes from the scales package. So in short:

```
geom_text(aes(x = id, y = end, label = comma(change)), vjust = 1, size = 3)
```

works but

```
geom_text(aes(x = id, y = end, label = formatter(change)), vjust = 1, size = 3)
```

does not.

The output looks like this:
[image: Waterfall plot]

Why doesn't geom_text accept my own formatting function? I'm sure it's something simple but I cannot see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is an issue with the environment in the `ggplot` call. If you add `environment = environment()`, it works:

```
  ggplot(mydf, aes(Description, fill = type), environment = environment()) + 
    geom_rect(aes(x = Description, xmin = id - 0.45, xmax = id + 0.45, ymin = end, ymax = start)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = formatter) +
    scale_x_discrete("", breaks = levels(mydf$Description), labels = strwr(levels(mydf$Description))) +
    geom_text(aes(x = id, y = end, label = formatter(change)), vjust = 1, size = 3)
```

As I understand it, this is because the function from `scales` is available in the global environment, but since you're defining `formatter` inside the function `plotIt()`, it is not available.

You can see this by the fact that if you run your code outside a defined function (start from inside your curly brackets), it all works. That is because this puts `formatter` in the global environment.

As a bit more explanation, you're error message is: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "formatter"`. If you look at the `base` function `eval()`, the default `envir` argument is `parent.frame()`. If you look at the output from `environment()`, you see it's `<environment: R_GlobalEnv>`. So when `eval()` operates, this tells it to look in the right place.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Indeed it fixed the problem. Now all there's left for me to do is understanding why. How come it works for labels = formatter in the scale_y_continuous but not in the geom_text? Is it due to the aes call?

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation. I figured it must have something to do with the environment too, but I still don't get why the code works for scale_y_continuous without the environment=environment() while it is needed for geom_text. Strange right?

Comment: That's right, inside the `aes()` ggplot looks in the global environment or the defined data.frame (`data =`). You can see that your other function `strwr` is also working outside the `aes()`.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the [waterfall package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/waterfall/index.html).
Here's a brief [example](http://lamages.blogspot.de/2012/05/waterfall-charts-in-style-of-economist.html) showing the functionality.
I think you wont have to care so much about the formatting.

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.